# Помогите с циклом в Пайтоне

Tags: python, while

После генерации рандомных букв и слов цикл выводит одну и туже строчку. Не понимаю как сделать, чтобы она обновлялась?

```
from mnemonic import Mnemonic
import random
import string


my_mnemonic = Mnemonic("english")
words = my_mnemonic.generate(128)

Running = True


def generate_alphanum_random_string(length):
    letters_and_digits = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    rand_string = ''.join(random.sample(letters_and_digits, length))
    while running:
      print('A:' + rand_string, '| M:', words)




generate_alphanum_random_string(31)
```

Comment: а почему у тебя нет отступов ?

Comment: ну вот, другое дело ))

Comment: да, ты прав, я проверил, действительно выводится одно и то же

Comment: посмотри, я добавил в код пару строк, я проверил, так работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что строка генерируется до цикла и моё решение в том, чтобы переместить строку генерации в само тело цикла, т.е. после `while`
Строчки, которые находятся до цикла `while` можно убрать, но я их оставил, чтобы вам было проще сравнивать мой код со своим кодом. В мой код я добавил ( скопировал ) всего две строки перед инструкцией `print`

```
from mnemonic import Mnemonic
import random
import string


my_mnemonic = Mnemonic("english")
words = my_mnemonic.generate(128) // это лишнее

Running = True


def generate_alphanum_random_string(length):
    letters_and_digits = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    rand_string = ''.join(random.sample(letters_and_digits, length)) // это лишнее
    while running:
      words = my_mnemonic.generate(128)
      rand_string = ''.join(random.sample(letters_and_digits, length))
      print('A:' + rand_string, '| M:', words)




generate_alphanum_random_string(31)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Но всё же нужно добавить пояснение текстом, либо комментарии в код, а лучше и то и другое.

Comment: @stefano пожалуйста, выберите мой ответ и поставьте галочку зелёную, если вам всё понятно. Пояснение я сейчас добавлю